# UIViewController base class - is it good or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have to apply single logic for gesture recongnizer to all `UIViewController` elements in my app.

I thought of creating a base class. However, as far as I know we should add extra layer to inheritance chain only in purpose of strong necessity.

What is the most efficient way to add functionality I mentioned above to my project, without copy-pasting code to each of mine controllers?

Comment: use baseviewcontroller and invoke the subclass for base class

Comment: Base controllers are simple and everybody is using them. However, you will run into problems once you start using `UITableViewController`, `UINavigationController`, `UICollectionViewController` etc. If possible, add the functionality using a category and turn it on explicitly on every controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can use extension of `UIViewController`

```
extension UIViewController
{
   // write code that has to be used in all view controllers
   func applyTheRequiredPropertiesToGestureRecognizer(gr:UIGestureRecognizer)
   {
      // do whatever you want to do
   }
}
```

Later while using

```
class SomeViewController:UIViewController{

   let gestureRecog = UIGestureRecognizer()

   //call the method 
   func someMethod()
   {
     self.applyTheRequiredPropertiesToGestureRecognizer(gestureRecog)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a baseviewController and do all the functions which are generic or used at most of the view controllers like an alert.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
 func yourGestureRecogniser() {
  // do the process
 }
}
```

Then inherit the base view to other view controllers like this,

```
class ViewController1: BaseViewController {
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourGestureRecogniser()
 } 
}

class ViewController2: BaseViewController {
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourGestureRecogniser()
 } 
}
```

customize the gesture function as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Using base controller is certainly a common approach.

A common base controller often becomes a dumping ground for functionality that is used in multiple-but-not-all controllers, so it become overkill.

I also followed this pattern in my project but later it becomes complicated for me when i start using other controllers like `UITableViewController, UICollectionViewController` etc.

Agreed with [Sulthan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44254972/uiviewcontroller-base-class-is-it-good-or-not#comment75518820_44254972): **using a category and turn it on explicitly on every controller** would definitely be a better option.

Comment: Very good comment about the dumping ground for functionality. I have seen to much similar code, e.g. for creating different types of navigation bar buttons which should be in specific controllers but it ended up in a base controller. A typical example of bad architecture is when a controller has to turn off some functionality provided by the base controller.